# Getting higher results than expected with 2 joins

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the query I have:

```
SELECT  p.id, COUNT(c.id) AS comments, COUNT(a.id) AS answers
FROM posts_tbl AS p
LEFT JOIN post_reply_tbl AS c ON c.post_id = p.id AND c.type IN (1,3)
LEFT JOIN post_reply_tbl AS a ON a.post_id = p.id AND a.type = 2
GROUP BY p.id
```

What I am supposed to get as results is:

```
ID  Answers Comments
1   3       4
2   1       1
3   0       1
```

But instead I am getting:

```
ID  Answers Comments
1   12      12
2   1       1
3   0       1
```

When I use just 1 of the LEFT JOINs no matter which one it gives me the right amount for answers/comments (depending on which LEFT JOIN I use). But when I use them both it gives me the second result.

Sample result data with when using *:

```
id  username    date                subject                     year    brand   model   type    bodywork                    text                                                    image       chassis         id  post_id answer_id   username        text    date                type    id  post_id answer_id   username        text            date                type
1   Sinan Samet 2013-02-18 20:18:19 Dit is een test onderwerp   2006    Audi    A4  TFSI 2.0    TFSI 2.0 QUATTRO - 200pk    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing ...   test.jpg    345215453213425 5   1       NULL        Sinan Samet     Test    2013-02-26 09:19:22 1       1   1       NULL        Jan Willem      Bla             2013-02-26 14:14:17 2
1   Sinan Samet 2013-02-18 20:18:19 Dit is een test onderwerp   2006    Audi    A4  TFSI 2.0    TFSI 2.0 QUATTRO - 200pk    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing ...   test.jpg    345215453213425 5   1       NULL        Sinan Samet     Test    2013-02-26 09:19:22 1       2   1       NULL        Peter           Nee toch niet   2013-02-26 15:12:26 2
1   Sinan Samet 2013-02-18 20:18:19 Dit is een test onderwerp   2006    Audi    A4  TFSI 2.0    TFSI 2.0 QUATTRO - 200pk    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing ...   test.jpg    345215453213425 5   1       NULL        Sinan Samet     Test    2013-02-26 09:19:22 1       3   1       NULL        Homer Simpson   Doh!            2013-02-26 14:33:18 2
1   Sinan Samet 2013-02-18 20:18:19 Dit is een test onderwerp   2006    Audi    A4  TFSI 2.0    TFSI 2.0 QUATTRO - 200pk    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing ...   test.jpg    345215453213425 6   1       NULL        Bart Simpson    Yo      2013-02-26 08:38:37 1       1   1       NULL        Jan Willem      Bla             2013-02-26 14:14:17 2
```

Comment: some simple data maybe ?

Comment: This is what I am getting when I use * to see the errors. http://oi53.tinypic.com/4gjd6o.jpg

Comment: please select some data and post it here i cant se your image

Comment: I editted my question with some sample data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select
    p.id,
    COALESCE(c.comments,0) AS comments,
    COALESCE(a.answers, 0) AS answers
from
    posts_tbl as p
    left join (
        select post_id, count(*) as comments
        from post_reply_tbl
        where type in (1,3)
        group by post_id
    ) as c on p.id = c.post_id
    left join (
        select post_id, count(*) as answers
        from post_reply_tbl
        where type = 2
        group by post_id
    ) as a on p.id = a.post_id
order by id ;
```

Comment: Exactly. JOIN and then using COUNT to produce aggregate subtotals gives you a count across the entire result set. Using joined subqueries allows you to generate a specific result set for a specific post ID, and then subtotal it up.

Comment: Im sorry but this gives me NULL for all comments and 1 for all answers

Comment: @Xegano. There were some bits left from earlier try. Try again.

Comment: Still same thing. The thing is that it does work when I use just one of the left joins instead of two of them I don't know if that's of any help..

Comment: @Xegano: See the edit. Also check my answer in this similar question: [Help with this query](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17012/help-with-this-query/17016#17016)

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot its working now!! Just need to change the last "order by" to "group by" though

Comment: No, you don't need `group by` there.

Comment: Well in my case I do need it. If I don't group them it shows a new row for each time repeating the ids. When I use group by it shows 3 rows

Comment: What are you talking about? Isn't `id` the Primary Key of `posts_tbl`?

Comment: Yes it is, if I do it without group by it shows id "1" 4 times with the same result somehow

Comment: Are you sure you have `group by post_id` in both the subqueries?